# Websphere application stop error : BUNDLE_CLASSPATH_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION in: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ExternalMessages

Tags: websphere

I am using RAD IDE and using Websphere Application Server 8.5.
Whenever I am trying to remove my deployed application (ABC.cba file) and stop the server, I am getting the below error :

> [4/12/17 12:18:23:663 IST] 00000157 SystemErr     R
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2017-04-12 12:18:23.663
>   !MESSAGE NLS missing message:
>   **BUNDLE_CLASSPATH_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION** in:
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ExternalMessages

How to rectify the above error, can anyone help me out ?